# Parse string in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, parsing

I want to parse this value `"AuthDate": "2021-08-17T19:03:27+04:00"` like 17/08/21, 19:03:27

I tried this `var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:MM:SS")`  but its not working

Comment: Have you parsed it correctly and only pending to display the final format?

Comment: yeah, Im parsing "AuthDate" value , saving it in variable and than tried to convert with formatter

Comment: let me know if the answer below is what you needed, accept it if you think it's correct 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you would need to parse the string that you've got into an object that kotlin can use, and then, you can use that object to format it to whichever format suits you :

```
fun main() {
    val string = "2021-08-17T19:03:27+04:00"
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
    val parsedDate = formatter.parse(string)
    val displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:MM:SS")
    val result = displayFormatter.format(parsedDate)
    println(result)
}
```